# Multiple row and multiple column conditions in mysql

Tags: mysql

With this query,

```
select *, from_unixtime(date_modified, '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s') as date_m 
from orc_bug_history_table v
where field_name = 'resolution'
and v.old_value IN ('6','60', '201', '202', '211', '221')
and bug_id ='630021'
```

I get the following results,

```
3462530 1001    630021  resolution  6   60  0   1484900395  2017 20th January 04:19:55
3462531 1001    630021  resolution  60  201 0   1484900610  2017 20th January 04:23:30
3462533 1001    630021  resolution  201 202 0   1484900775  2017 20th January 04:26:15
3462538 1001    630021  resolution  202 211 0   1484900926  2017 20th January 04:28:46
3462546 1001    630021  resolution  211 221 0   1484901180  2017 20th January 04:33:00
3462552 1001    630021  resolution  221 85  0   1484901557  2017 20th January 04:39:17
```

Here I have restricted my query to bug_id = '630021'. But what I need is, I need to retrieve all the bug_id which have the exact same sequence of rows of old_value mentioned in the query. i.e ( '6','60', '201', '202', '211', '221'). I need this sequence. My table consists other old values than those mentioned here. And some of the bug_id's can have just few values mentioned and not all.

I tried IN ALL, but seems it will work only in Oraclesql and not in mysql. I have also tried the following but couldn't figure out a proper way.

```
select *, from_unixtime(date_modified, '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s') as date_m 
from orc_bug_history_table v
where field_name = 'resolution'
and v.old_value IN (select '6','60', '201', '202', '211', '221' from dual)
and bug_id ='630021'
```

Expected o/p

```
3462530 1001    630021  resolution  6   60  0   1484900395  2017 20th January 04:19:55
3462531 1001    630021  resolution  60  201 0   1484900610  2017 20th January 04:23:30
3462533 1001    630021  resolution  201 202 0   1484900775  2017 20th January 04:26:15
3462538 1001    630021  resolution  202 211 0   1484900926  2017 20th January 04:28:46
3462546 1001    630021  resolution  211 221 0   1484901180  2017 20th January 04:33:00
3462552 1001    630021  resolution  221 85  0   1484901557  2017 20th January 04:39:17
3462551 1001    630022  resolution  6   60  0   1484900395  2017 20th January 04:19:55
3462552 1001    630022  resolution  60  201 0   1484900610  2017 20th January 04:23:30
3462553 1001    630022  resolution  201 202 0   1484900775  2017 20th January 04:26:15
3462554 1001    630022  resolution  202 211 0   1484900926  2017 20th January 04:28:46
3462555 1001    630022  resolution  211 221 0   1484901180  2017 20th January 04:33:00
3462556 1001    630022  resolution  221 85  0   1484901557  2017 20th January 04:39:17
```

Any help!!

Comment: What should be the expected result?

Comment: Need the query for the values of bug_id which follows the edited pattern

Comment: Only for test,change `IN` for this  `v.old_value LIKE '%6%'`

Comment: Like will result in rows which doesn't have sequence.

Comment: Is only to see if there are hidden characters or try with trim(v.old_value)